# Realm: Getting -[__NSArrayM UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, realm, realm-migration

I am Getting crash in app upgrade scenario. It gives below error and warning. But this issue happens only when I have AppStore build installed and on top of that I install my new testflight build. 
If I install developer build on AppStore build, than it works fine.

**Error:**

> [__NSArrayM UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

**Warning:** An RLMRealm instance was deallocated during a write transaction and all pending changes have been rolled back. Make sure to retain a reference to the RLMRealm for the duration of the write transaction.

It crashes straight away when you tap app icon, So, I dont have any stack trace.

Realm version: 0.96.3 &
Xcode version: 7.3

Below is my migration code for that.

```
RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
    config.schemaVersion = 3;

    if (oldSchemaVersion < 2)
    {
        [migration enumerateObjects:DB_Class1.className
                              block:^(RLMObject *oldObject, RLMObject *newObject) {
                                  newObject[@"thisIsArray_1"] = nil;
                              }];
        [migration enumerateObjects:DB_Class2.className
                              block:^(RLMObject *oldObject, RLMObject *newObject) {
                                  newObject[@"thisIsInt_1"] = 0;
                                  newObject[@"thisIsInt_2"] = 0;
                                  newObject[@"thisIsInt_3"] = 0;
                              }];            
    }
```

All of the above `newObjects` are added in this version only.

Update 1: I can see `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded`for android. Is there any eqvivalent in iOS? I only found `deleteAllObjects`. If so, thn I can simply delete my old realm data and save new one.

Thanks.

Comment: see this once it helps you https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3422

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, Yes, based on that I had upgraded realm, but couldnt solve

Comment: The error message simply says that `UTF8String` is sent to an `NSArray` object rather than the expected `NSString` object

Comment: But it dosent happen in developer build. My data remains the same for developer and release build, but, this happens only during release build.

Answer (score 1):

Realm Cocoa added the `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded` option (on `RLMRealmConfiguration`) in version 0.102.0. This should allow you to sidestep your migration issues. See the change notes [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Comment: Ok. will look into that. Thanks